# Networking - RIP routing WAN connection in Packet Tracer

Tags: networking, command-line-interface, router, wan

Anyone here knows how to deal with networking?

Here's my network scheme in Packet Tracer:

[image: WAN network scheme]

How do I do the routing in CLI to connect those three routers?

Note that the routers are in different cities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In networking we are having routing protocol to do the configuration.

Here i'll show you the RIP.  I hope you know the IP assigning parts and all.

```
interface FastEthernet0/0
 ip address 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface Serial0/0
 ip address 10.0.0.1 255.0.0.0
 clock rate 64000
!
interface Serial0/1
 no ip address
 shutdown
interface FastEthernet0/0
 ip address 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface Serial0/0
 ip address 10.0.0.1 255.0.0.0
 clock rate 64000
!
interface Serial0/1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
router rip
 network 10.0.0.0
 network 192.168.1.0

ip classless
!
!
```

Do the same in the other two routers... then you are good to go...

Answer (score 1):

On each router enter the following commands:

```
conf t
router rip
network ***.***.***.*** ^^^.^^^.^^^.^^^
.
.

end
```

where the `***.***.***.***` is the  ip of a directly connected network and the `^^^.^^^.^^^.^^^` is this networks mask.

repeat the "network ... " command for each directly connected network, and you should be good to go, the rip then takes care of sending advertising messages every 15 sec. or so.